# Can i create 64-bit setup using pure InstallScript?

Tags: 64-bit, installshield

Can i create 64-bit setup.exe file using InstallScript project in InstallShield 2009?
Documentation is only about msi projects.
Or tell me alternative way to use 64-bit registry keys, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, no, you cannot create a 64-bit InstallSciprt Setup.EXE.  The Setup.EXE is a 32-bit application, but I don't think that's exactly what you were asking.

I think you were asking if you could author an InstallScript package that can run native 64-bit Registry/file system commands, and the answer to that is "yes".

For the Registry, which you specifically asked about, see:
[REGDB_OPTIONS](http://documentation.installshield.com/robo/projects/installshield12langref/LangrefREGDB_OPTIONS.htm)

Add option `REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY`, and then you can call the Registry functions as you normally would, but they will operate on the 64-bit section of the Registry.  To switch back to 32-bit, remove the `REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY` option.

Comment: Thanks. I would use REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY + WOW64FSREDIRECTION.

Answer (score 1):

When using REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY, be sure to always remove the setting before you leave your function as this can cause your setup.exe to not create an uninstall log in some versions of InstallShield; so while your setup.exe may run the uninstall it'll leave all of the files on the system because it does not create a Setup.ilg file

begin:

```
    if (SYSINFO.bIsWow64) then
    REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTIONS | REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;
endif;
```

end:

```
if (SYSINFO.bIsWow64) then
    REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTION_USE_DEFAULT_OPTIONS;
endif;
```